# Scrapy is saving URLs with triple slashes ///

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I don't know why scrapy is doing this, but it happened two times in different places.

I think both times it was because I was trying to add the `http:` to an url.

```
item['product_link'] = urljoin(ABS_URL,''.join(item['product_link']).replace('/', '').encode('utf-8').strip())
```

`ABS` is adding the `http:`
Also tried adding it there but I'm always getting 3 /// if I don't add anything the item has only one /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how `urljoin` works. If the base only contains scheme (and not any domain part), the result will contain triple slash:

```
>>> urlparse.urljoin('http://', 'foo.html')
'http:///foo.html'
>>> urlparse.urljoin('http:', 'foo.html')
'http:///foo.html'
>>> urlparse.urljoin('http://foo', 'bar.html')
'http://foo/bar.html'
```

From your code it looks like you use it to only add scheme to the formed `product_link`. In that case, simple concatenation would suffice:

```
item['product_link'] = 'http:' + ''.join(item['product_link']).replace('/', '').encode('utf-8').strip()
```